# Container's height doesn't change with content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an bootstrap site where my div can't fit inside a container, div overlaps container height. Div has a property `position: fixed` is it still possible to fit it inside the container?

Code:

```css
.container{
    width: 92%;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
  }
  .row {
      margin-right: 50px;
      margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .row:before, .row:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  .container:before, .container:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  .row:after{
    clear: both;
  }

  .container:after {
      clear: both;
  }

  .col-md-3{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 21%;
    padding: 0;
    top: 72px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1040;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        //More code
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If something is `position: fixed` it doesn't get the height of the content. Instead make it `position: inline-block` and make a `<div style="position= fixed;" >` around the `<div class="col-md-3">`

Comment: What is the containing element and it's css?

Comment: First of all, your `position:fixed` is being overriden by `position-relative` in another css file. But you might actually want to use relative and instead change `top: 72px` to `margin-top:72px`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `position:fixed`, try `position:absolute` and apply `position: relative` to the container. Now you can position the element relative to the content.

When you are applying `position:fixed`, it wil be positioned based on `body` tag.

Comment: fixed position is relative to browser window, not body tag

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but sadly it didn't work out for me. The col-md-3 just moved out of it's original position where it suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

No. Position: fixed makes an element fixed relative to the browser window. It ignores its container position altogether. You might try position: absolute instead.

Comment: Using position: absolute didn't fix my issue. Still overlaps the container.

Comment: Show more code. What is the container and it's css?

Comment: Try removing position altogether then. Neither fixed nor absolute will force the container height to expand. Either relative or static may be what you want. However you might need a better working example to illustrate your problem, and what it is you need to achieve.

Comment: There is a site actually what has achieved what I'm trying to do. http://csgocasino.net/roulette the left side panel. It uses fixed position and all fits in the container.

Comment: There is another div in that example with position:relative which determines height of container.

Answer (score 0):

it might be helpful

```css
.container {
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    width:250px;
    background-color:white;
    height:250px;   
    padding: 5px;
}
.col-md-3 {
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;    
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px;
    background-color:#ccffcc;
    border-style:solid;  
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>some code here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```